# Isometries to prove rhombus?

Tags: geometry

Suppose that the diagonals of a quadrilateral are perpendicular bisectors of each other. Use isometries to prove that the quadrilateral must be a rhombus.
Im unsure how to use isometries to prove this

Comment: What isometries do you know?

Comment: Reflection, translation, rotation

Comment: (some would add glide reflection as an isometry of the Euclidean plane).

Answer (score 0):

This was getting a little long for a comment, but is more a hint than an answer

Hint: Which of the isometries take a rhombus to itself?

You don't know that these isometries apply to the figure you are given, but there is no real point in trying isometries which wouldn't apply to a rhombus.

Now think about what you need to prove about your given figure in order to show that it is a rhombus (all sides have the same length?). You are told nothing about the sides, of course, but an isometry leaves lengths the same, so can you use isometries to demonstrate that the lengths are the same?

If you try this approach, you will find that you can use the information about the diagonals to show that the isometries (of the whole plane) you hope will work do actually leave your figure invariant, and do really map one side to another.

Comment: Actually you haven't really asked a definite question. My notes above suggest a method by which you can use isometries to prove that the four sides of your quadrilateral are equal. So if you are asking for a method, this is (most of) an answer to your question. Pick isometries which leave your figure invariant (use the properties of the diagonals to show this works) - then show that they take sides to sides and hence that the sides are all equal.